# Am I using the proper command?

Tags: linux, grep, uniq

I am trying to write a one-line command on terminal to count all the unique *"gene-MIR"* in a very large file. The *"gene-MIR"* are followed by a series of numbers ex. *gene-MIR334223*, *gene-MIR633235*, *gene-MIR53453* ... *etc*, and there are multiples of the same *"gene-MIR"* ex. *gene-MIR342433* may show up *10x* in the script.

My question is, how do I write a command that will annotate the unique "gene-MIR" that are present in my file?

The commands I have been using so far is:

1. `grep -c "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | uniq`
2. `grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort -u`

The first command provides me with a count; however, I believe it does not include the number series after *"MIR"* and is only counting how many *"gene-MIR"* itself are present.

Thanks!

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7EcD.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3TtR.png)

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: `grep -c` counts the *number of lines* matching the pattern, so if a line contains the pattern twice, the count increments by just one. `grep` without options prints the whole line matching the pattern, so depending on the input, `sort` will get to see unrelated context. As mentioned, you have to show representative sample input.

Comment: Hi there! Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have attached a photo to the original post, basically, in the image you can see the red highlighted region, I am trying to code for that region "gene-MIR" and I want it to include the numbers following "MIR" ex. "gene-MIR8061" and there are multiples of the same, I want my command to count it once. @BenjaminW.

Comment: The example shows different "gene-MIR8061" followed by one of -3, -4, -5; are those considered unique and to be counted separately? or maybe ignore each -3/-4/-5 and count all of them together?

Comment: I would like to ignore -3/-4/-5 etc and only count the number following "MIR" example "gene-MIR8061" by itself only. @Milag

Comment: Would you think I need to add a regular expression with grep so it can also include the digits following 'MIR'? @Milag

Comment: please copy and paste part of the original text file. Don't put it in an image

Comment: @testtubeshawty12 - do either of the first 2 answers work for you? if not, one refinement: do you want to show all unique genes, only a total count of them, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the entries are are on separate lines, try this:

```
grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

If the entries are mixed up with other text, and the system has *GNU* `grep` try this:

```
grep -o 'gene-MIR[0-9]*' myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

To get the total count:

```
grep -o 'gene-MIR[0-9]*' myfile.txt  | wc -l
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think this is it; however, I was not able to get a count for it when I entered the command? It just sorted it out but hadn't given me a count. @agc

Comment: Do you think I need to add a regular expression to the command so it can also incorporate the digits following 'MIR'? @agc

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! So the command that I just did extracted all the unique "gene-MIR" followed by a series of numbers, is there a way where I can get the command to tell me how many there are exactly or would I have to manually count? @agc

Comment: In total there are almost more than 4000 gene-MIR; however, these are not unique, as they are annotated more than once, is there a way where I can get the command to tell me exactly how many unique "gene-MIR####" there are? @agc.

Comment: Sorry to keep troubling @agc. How do I change the command so it shows me all the "gene-MIR" followed by either a word and/or number. So basically any alphanumeric value? ex. "gene-MIR4243FG".  Thanks!

Comment: @testtubeshawty12, Read the [`grep` docs on bracket expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html).  Hint:  look for `[:alpha:]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have information like this:

```
Inf1
Inf2
Inf1
Inf2
```

And you want to know the amount of "inf" kinds, you always need to sort it first. Only afterwards you can start counting.

**Edit**

I've created a similar file, containing the examples, mentioned in the requester's comment, as follows:

```
Nonsense
gene-MIR4232
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR93284
gene-MIR4232
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR93284
More nonsense
```

On that, I've applied both commands, as mentioned in the question:

```
grep -c "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | uniq
```

Which results in 6, just like the following command:

```
grep -c "gene-MIR" myfile.txt
```

Why? The question here is "How many lines contain the string "gene-MIR"?".
This is clearly not the requested information.

The other command also is not correct:

```
grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort -u
```

The result:

```
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR4232
gene-MIR93284
```

Explanation:
`grep "gene-MIR" ...` means: show all the lines, which contain "gene-MIR"
`| sort -u` means: sort the displayed lines and if there are multiple instances of the same, only show one of them.

Also this is not what the requester wants. Therefore I have following proposal:

```
grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

With following result:

```
      2 gene-MIR2334
      2 gene-MIR4232
      2 gene-MIR93284
```

This is more what the requester is looking for, I presume.

What does it mean?
`grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt` : only show the lines which contain "gene-MIR"
`| sort` : sort the lines, which are shown. Like this, you get an intermediate result like this:

```
    gene-MIR2334
    gene-MIR2334
    gene-MIR4232
    gene-MIR4232
    gene-MIR93284
    gene-MIR93284
```

`| uniq -c` : group those results together and show the count for every instance.

Unfortunately, the example is badly chosen as every instance occurs exactly two times. Therefore, for clarification purposes, I've created another "myfile.txt", as follows:

```
Nonsense
gene-MIR4232
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR93284
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR2334
gene-MIR93284
More nonsense
```

I've applied the same command again:

```
grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

With following result:

```
      3 gene-MIR2334
      1 gene-MIR4232
      2 gene-MIR93284
```

Here you can see in a much clearer way that the proposed command is correct.

... and your next question is: "Yes, but is it possible to sort the result?", on which I answer:

```
grep "gene-MIR" myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

With following result:

```
      1 gene-MIR4232
      2 gene-MIR93284
      3 gene-MIR2334
```

Have fun!

Comment: Inside my file is a large data set consisting of thousands of genomes and other information that I do not need. From the data set I need to be able to extract the unique miRNA genes ex. gene-MIR4232, gene-MIR2334, gene-MIR93284 ... etc and get an exact count. @Dominique

Comment: @testtubeshawty12: I've edited my answer according to your comment.